# What is "Video Overdrive"?

Tags: display

My monitor's on screen menu has some mysterious settings, one being "Video Overdrive".  I tried it, but saw no obvious difference.  What is it?

The monitor is an HP ZR24w.  However, the term seems to be used more widely than for one brand.

Comment: Have you checked the online specifications for your monitor.  If its not explained there it will be tough to determine what it does

Comment: You have a term and a brand name, and a plethora of search engines...

Comment: Google didn't turn up anything meaningful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first result in a search for "HP Video Overdrive" returned [a manual](http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/document?cc=us&lc=en&dlc=en&docname=c02013914) for one of their models that supports it, listing a description of what it does:

> **Reduces motion blur in video and fast moving games.** Sets the OverDrive feature on or off; the default setting is Off. (select models)

I'd be going out on a limb, but I'm guessing it's their proprietary way of increasing frame rates so motion blur is less perceived by the human eye, likely done by means of optimizing color, anti-aliasing and refresh rates.